# Convert geometry_msgs/twist to asctec_msgs/CtrlInput

Tags: ros, velocity, geometry-msgs, pelican

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am working with an asctec pelican and ros. I wanna control the pelican via ros, but the pelican need asctec_msgs/CtrlInput messages. But most things in ros publishes geometry_msgs/twist as velocity commands.

My question is, is there something in ros which can be used to translate the twist messages to CtrlInput messages ?

Or does somebody knows something about the asctec/CtrlInput? I would write the node myself, but I do not know much about the CtrlInput messages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68587/convert-geometry_msgs/twist-to-asctec_msgs/ctrlinput/) by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 336 on 2013-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the STARMAC package, they use AscTec Pelican. http://www.ros.org/wiki/starmac-ros-pkg

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2013-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2